# Unique textures on multiple lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, path-effects

i'm wondering how these horitzontal lines have been textured, it doesn't seem to have been done with a brush. Something that is also interesting is that where ever the horizontal lines converge with the logo it sort of glows/thickens.

[image]

Comment: It could be a brush, but the easier method would be something like a concrete texture placed on top of the lines with the blending mode `Multiply`. Of course, part of the "effect is also that the lines are faded around the sides and the center. This you could do with a layer mask and a soft round brush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say, but my initial reaction is that the lines are all uniform white strokes. A dark textured layer has then been put on top and partly erased in certain areas. Then an outer glow added to the logo. Maybe some other filters applied. Hard to recreate as the designer probably just played around with various filters and transparency settings until they were happy with it